# Search for bitcoin with ipv4 address

Tags: technical-analysis

I am working on a way to monitor bitcoin transactions and found that on blockchain info it's possible to find info about a bitcoin by ipv4 address. Is there an API supporting this on a larger scale? Or is bitcoin info using it's own database to connect ip with transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All bitcoin transaction are not linked to user ip address, unless some wallets which links your transactions to your ip address.

I don't know what blockchain.info doing but what i know it's not possible to track any bitcoin transaction through ip address.